# Bayesian time-to-event modelling which allows time-dependent covariates, time-dependent coefficients and imputed datasets

Tags: r, bayesian, survival, time-varying-covariate

Looking for recommendations on approach to modelling a patient disease cohort with treatment data (differing durations and doses), follow-up and survival data. Each subject has several covariates, some of which also vary through the follow-up period - i.e. both treatment effect and covariates are time-dependent. The proportional hazards assumption seems to be violated for several covariates, hence I need an approach which does not rely on this.  Ideally I like to do this in Bayesian framework, to estimate the association of treatment with survival in this cohort.

[To round things off, there are missing data which I've imputed by multiple imputation. So modelling estimations in each imputed dataset would need to be pooled to give a final estimate, but I'm putting that aside for now...]

Does anyone know of a Bayesian approach to this? Or is this a job for joint longitudinal and time-to-event modelling? I work primarily in R, so that would suit me best but interested in the approach primarily.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Questions that are only about software (e.g. error messages, code or packages, etc.)
are generally off topic here. If you have a substantive machine learning or
statistical question, please edit to clarify.

Comment: Apologies. Have reworded. Thanks for the feedback :-)

Comment: Thanks. The current version seems potentially broad to me, but I'll retract my close vote.